# Spring integration validation in split & aggregate flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to add filter to discard the flow and continue executing the main flow even after the failure and aggregate the splitter. the expected type for both error & success are same. there is no specific aggregator logic.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
     return f -> f
         .split(Orders.class, Orders::getItems)
         .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("enrichChannel"))
         .filter(Order.class, c -> c.getId() > 10 ? true : false,
             e -> e.discardChannel(validationError()))
         .handle(new MyHandler())
         .transform(new MapToObjectTransformer(Order.class))
         .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("transformChannel"))
         .filter(Order.class, c -> c.getTotal() > 100 ? true : false,
             e -> e.discardChannel(validationError())).handle( new transformer())
         .aggregate();
 }
            
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow validationErrorFlow() {
 return IntegrationFlows.from(validationError())
         .handle(new ValidationHandler())
         .get();
}
```

the discard channel is not joining back to the main flow to execute the next item in the split.

I can write route & subflow mapping but that will become too nested in route -> sub flows -> route -> subflows trying to solve this by using filters. is there a better way to perform validation and still continue the split for all the items in the flow.

Update 1:

```
.handle(request.class, (p, h) -> validator.validate(p)
.gateway("filterFlow.input")
.handle(new MyHandler())
.enrich(...)
.handle(...)
.enrich(...)
.handle(...)
.enrich(...)
.handle(...)
.aggregate();



@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow filterFlow() {
        return f -> f
                .filter(response.class, c -> c.isValidationStatus(), df -> df.discardFlow
                        (flow -> flow.handle(Message.class, (p, h) -> p.getPayload())));
    }
```

gateway is able to intercept the request but the flow executed `.handle(new MyHandler())` rather than the next item in `split()`

Update 2: (Answer) from Artem

```
.handle(request.class, (p, h) -> validator.validate(p))
    .filter(response.class,p -> p.isValidationStatus(), f -> f.discardChannel("aggregatorChannel"))
    .handle(new MyHandler())
    .enrich(...)
    .handle(...)
    .enrich(...)
    .handle(...)
    .enrich(...)
    .handle(...)
    .channel("aggregatorChannel")
    .aggregate();
```

This will do a conditional skip & continue on the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the discard channel is not joining back to the main flow to execute the next item in the split.

That's true. That's how it is designed. In most cases the discard flow is something like Dead Letter Queue in JMS. So, that is short one-way branch.

If you really would like to come back to the main flow, you should consider to use naming channel in the flow definition. I mean in the point where you would like to come back after compensation (discard) flow:

```
.filter(Order.class, c -> c.getId() > 10 ? true : false,
                    e -> e.discardFlow(sf -> sf
                            .gateway(validationError())
                            .channel("myHandleChannel")))
            .channel("myHandleChannel")
            .handle(new MyHandler())
```

I use `gateway()` because we need a reply from the discard flow to continue processing. We need that `.channel("myHandleChannel")` in the end of sub-flow because discard flow is a branch.

Another way to do that can be achieved with the `.gateway()` on the main flow:

```
.gateway("filterFlow.input")
.handle(new MyHandler())

...

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow filterFlow() {
    return f -> f
            .filter(Order.class, c -> c.getId() > 10 ? true : false,
                    e -> e.discardChannel(validationError()));
}
```

We send to the `discardChannel` the same request message, therefore a proper `replyChannel` header for the mentioned gateway is still there. Only what you need is to ensure a proper reply producing from the `.handle(new ValidationHandler())`.

Comment: You see. It isn't readable. Please, consider to edit your question with properly formatted code. Please, respect the help people provide for you.

Comment: Updated the question , one wrong press on the key board , formatting is messed up.

Comment: `rather than the next item in split()`. Sounds like a different question and it doesn't parallel your other sentence: `the discard channel is not joining back to the main flow`. I've answered to this concern. Otherwise it's not clear in your question what would you like to see. What you suggest in the end is the behavior by default: filter discards and returns control back to the main flow for the next splitted item, unless you use `throwExceptionOnRejection`, but that doesn't look like.

Comment: yes, the initial question is answered but was looking for a different behavior , the flow shouldn't execute after `gateway` and look for the next item in the split and `aggregate()` at the end. i tried throwExceptionOnRejection/ exception in discard channel, in that case whole flow is suspended completely and the remaining items in the split are discarded. going by the conversation route & sub flow is the only choice for this behavior rather than relying on the filter

Comment: Well, maybe your idea to go to the aggregator directly in the discard flow bypassing all those processing steps? The point is that when we use  filter with a standard behavior, the standard aggregator won't work because there won't be enough splitted items to group. So, you definitely might need to return somehow to the main flow from the discard sub-flow and just into the aggregator endpoint. For this purpose the named channel is a solution for you again.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i am trying to do. thats why my first question of returning from discardflow back to the main flow with the payload worked perfectly with your sample. i  am trying to figure out how to get to the `aggregate()` skipping all the subsequent steps or continue the steps if the filter returned `true`.  you mean to say read the named channel from the discarded flow in to the aggregate ?

Comment: You place a `.channel("aggregatorChannel")` before an `.aggregate()` and in the discard flow use `.channel("aggregatorChannel")` to send the discard flow result directly to the aggregtor. This way you shouldn't use the `.gateway()`, but my first suggestion with the `.filter()`. You know that is the different story. Let's start in the separate SO question! And consider this one as fixed.

Comment: i just fixed my code , what you suggested is pretty sleek , i never thought of placing a discardchannel receiver before the aggregate, always perceived the flow will break and never return to the main flow, once the discard started. discarding and receiving in the same continuous flow :) :D . as always thanks a ton!!

Comment: Ah! The task was so simple - just discard directly to the aggregator! :-)

Comment: Right, never forget that there are channels in between endpoints and you always can send messages to those channel from any place, including discard flow.

Comment: Comment startWith "You place a ..." is perfect it helped me fix a continuation of the flow given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290732/spring-integration-integrationflowadapter-how-to-use if the query string has http://localhost:8080/?names=sugar,,,,,salt thanks @ArtemBilan