# Spring Integration IntegrationFlowAdapter: how to use?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

At https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-flow-adapter I find this code example:

```
@Component
public class MyFlowAdapter extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {

    private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();

    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
          return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
    }

    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from(this::messageSource,
                      e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime)))
                 .split(this)
                 .transform(this)
                 .aggregate(a -> a.processor(this, null), null)
                 .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("thing1", "THING1"))
                 .filter(this)
                 .handle(this)
                 .channel(c -> c.queue("myFlowAdapterOutput"));
    }

    public String messageSource() {
         return "T,H,I,N,G,2";
    }

    @Splitter
    public String[] split(String payload) {
         return StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(payload);
    }

    @Transformer
    public String transform(String payload) {
         return payload.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Aggregator
    public String aggregate(List<String> payloads) {
           return payloads.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    @Filter
    public boolean filter(@Header Optional<String> thing1) {
            return thing1.isPresent();
    }

    @ServiceActivator
    public String handle(String payload, @Header String thing1) {
           return payload + ":" + thing1;
    }

}
```

Besides the fact that this code doesn't seem to compile with the latest version of Spring Integration, can anyone provide a working example how how one would use this MyFlowAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working variant of that sample according to the latest Spring Integration code base:

```
@Component
public class MyFlowAdapter extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {

    private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();

    public Instant nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : Instant.now();
    }

    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return fromSupplier(this::messageSource,
                e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime)))
                .split(this)
                .transform(this)
                .aggregate(this)
                .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("thing1", "THING1"))
                .filter(this)
                .handle(this)
                .channel(c -> c.queue("myFlowAdapterOutput"));
    }

    public String messageSource() {
        return "T,H,I,N,G,2";
    }

    @Splitter
    public String[] split(String payload) {
        return StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(payload);
    }

    @Transformer
    public String transform(String payload) {
        return payload.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Aggregator
    public String aggregate(List<String> payloads) {
        return payloads.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    @Filter
    public boolean filter(@Header Optional<String> thing1) {
        return thing1.isPresent();
    }

    @ServiceActivator
    public String handle(String payload, @Header String thing1) {
        return payload + ":" + thing1;
    }

}
```

Will fix that doc shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This code still works midway 2023, If i am not providing any message source, we can still call this flow using `@MessagingGateway`

for end to end trigger

- setup gateway for entry point(also this automatic trigger also works)
- setup input/output queue
- execute flow
- collect the response from the end of the channel
- return in response

Here is how I have tried to do it:

Gateway

```
package in.silentsudo.springintegrations.flowadapter;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;

@MessagingGateway
public interface FlowGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "initFlowChannel", replyChannel = "exitFlowChannel")
    String triggerFlow(String input);

}
```

IntegratioFlow

```
package in.silentsudo.springintegrations.flowadapter;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SampleFlowAdapter extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {
    private final MessageChannel initFlowChannel;
    private final MessageChannel exitFlowChannel;


    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(initFlowChannel)
                .split(this)
                .filter(this)
                .transform(this)
                .aggregate(this)
                .handle(this)
                .channel(exitFlowChannel);
    }

    @Splitter
    public Set<String> split(String input) {
        Set<String> strings = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet(input);
        log.info("Split items: {}", strings);
        return strings;
    }


    @Transformer
    public String transform(String input) {
        final String transformed = String.format("%s is transformed to %s", input, input.toUpperCase());
        log.info("Transformed: {}", transformed);
        return transformed;
    }


    @Filter
    public boolean isNonEmpty(Optional<String> input) {
        boolean isPresent = input.isPresent();
        log.info("Is Present: {}", isPresent);
        return isPresent;
    }


    @Aggregator
    public String aggregate(List<String> payloads) {
        String join = String.join(",", payloads);
        log.info("Join Result: {}", join);
        return join;
    }

    @ServiceActivator
    public String onServiceActivation(String input) {
        return input;
    }

}
```

Queue Configuration

```
package in.silentsudo.springintegrations.flowadapter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
public class FlowAdapterChannelConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel initFlowChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel exitFlowChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package in.silentsudo.springintegrations.controllers;

import in.silentsudo.springintegrations.flowadapter.FlowGateway;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SimpleController {

    private final FlowGateway gateway;

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, String> root(@RequestParam("names") String names) {
        String response = gateway.triggerFlow(names);
        return Map.of("status", "ok", "response", response);
    }

    @GetMapping("throw-error")
    public Map<String, String> throwError() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid state");
    }
}
```

Http call goes like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/?names=sugar,salt
```

**EDIT**: If by mistake an extra , is added in query like

```
http://localhost:8080/?names=sugar,,,,,salt
```

Then flow breaks, update flow to this in that case:

```
@Override
    protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(initFlowChannel)
                .split(this)
                .filter(String.class, StringUtils::hasText, e -> e.discardFlow(i ->i.channel("agreeAll")))
                .transform(this)
                .channel("agreeAll")
                .aggregate(this)
                .handle(this)
                .channel(exitFlowChannel);
    }
```